# Содержимое ячейки не должно выходить за пределы ячейки

Tags: c#, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

**Google Sheets**

Для наглядности, добавил картинку, вот этот эффект нужно применить к `таблице / листу / ячейке` с ужу имеющимися данными.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

Как c помощью `API` сделать так, чтобы содержимое ячейки не выходило за размеры ячейки ?

Я нашёл такое свойство как `WrapStrategy`

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#wrapstrategy

Необходимое мне эффект будет при `WrapStrategy = "CLIP"`

И вот накидал код...

Необходимый эффект у ячеек появляется, но если были какие либо данные в этих ячейках, они просто стираются.

```
        GridRange gridRange = new GridRange();
        gridRange.SheetId = 0;

        CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat();
        cellFormat.WrapStrategy = "CLIP";

        CellData cellData = new CellData();
        cellData.UserEnteredFormat = cellFormat;
        
        RepeatCellRequest repeatCellRequest = new RepeatCellRequest();
        repeatCellRequest.Cell = cellData;
        repeatCellRequest.Fields = "*";
        repeatCellRequest.Range = gridRange;
        
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.Requests = new List<Request>();
        batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.Requests.Add(new Request
        {
            RepeatCell = repeatCellRequest
        });

        var batchUpdateRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest, spreadSheetID);

        var response = batchUpdateRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: у Вас там выбор небольшой...либо `CLIP` либо `LEGACY_WRAP`. помимо `WrapStrategy` ничего другого и нет вроде подходящего для вашей задачи

Comment: `но если бы не было данных в ячейках, иначе этот способ стирает всё содержимое.` вот это непонятно ... странное поведение, не могли бы вы подробнее описать его в вопросе?

Comment: вот весь список свойств ячейки: `numberFormat, backgroundColor, backgroundColorStyle, borders, padding, horizontalAlignment, verticalAlignment, wrapStrategy, textDirection, textFormat, hyperlinkDisplayType, textRotation`. wrapStrategy - единственный вариант для вас

Comment: @МихаилРебров угу, вот только можно как то применить `wrapStrategy` к ячейке / ячейкам так, чтобы при этом остались данные которые в них находятся до применения ?

Answer (score -1):

Я новичок в программировании, но я бы перед применением метода wrapStrategy сохранял в переменную содержимое ячейки, дальше применил бы метод wrapStrategy, а потом вставил данные в ячейку.